# Query with custom object type fails to convert custom fields in Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to query an Azure Table Storage instance from an Azure Function to retrieve either a single or multiple entities according to particular conditions (filters).

According to [Microsoft's documentation of the `Azure.Data.Tables` SDK querying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data.tables-readme?view=azure-dotnet#query-table-entities) (I'm using `v12.8.0`) this should be possible by substituting the `TableEntity` type with your custom strongly-typed object when calling `Query`. Their snippets example its capability as below

```cs
// Define a strongly typed entity by implementing the ITableEntity interface.
public class OfficeSupplyEntity : ITableEntity
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }
}

...
// Given this model class definition, here is how you'd write a query
double priceCutOff = 6.00;
Pageable<OfficeSupplyEntity> queryResultsLINQ = tableClient.Query<OfficeSupplyEntity>(ent => ent.Price >= priceCutOff);
```

Following this, I've a model defined as such

```cs
public class MyModel : ITableEntity
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }

    public int PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string? PropertyB { get; set; }
    public Guid? PropertyC { get; set; }
    public Version PropertyD { get; set; }
    public Version PropertyE { get; set; }
    public Guid PropertyF { get; set; }
}
```

When I call to retrieve a single entity, as below, the entity properties are populated and the custom properties are visible in the objects `Value` Results View.

```cs
Response<TableEntity> results = _tableClient.GetEntity<TableEntity>(partitionKey, recordKey);
```

However, if I try to retrieve it using the custom model as shown below (following the docs example), the entity properties are populated by all customer properties are their default values.

```cs
Response<MyModel> results = _tableClient.GetEntity<MyModel>(partitionKey, recordKey);
```

The same is true when trying to use `Query<MyModel>` with a filter upon the Guid property `PropertyC` (as shown below), the `Pageable<MyModel>` result is empty. Presumably as it's unable to convert the `TableEntity` to `MyModel`?

```cs
_tableClient.Query<MyModel>(e => e.PropertyC == PropertyC)
```

Does anyone know why querying with a custom model doesn't appear to initialise correctly, as expected in the documentation? I've considered creating a custom converter, but performance is key with this function so therefore minimal custom-code overhead is needed.

### Update

For context, these are the field definitions in the Table Storage

- `PartitionKey`: `String`
- `RowKey` : `String`
- `Timestamp` : `DateTimeOffset`
- `PropertyA` : `Int32`
- `PropertyB` : `String`
- `PropertyC` : `Guid`
- `PropertyD` : `String`
- `PropertyE` : `String`
- `PropertyF` : `Guid`

In a record, either `PropertyC` or `PropertyD` might have a value, but not both or neither. And `PropertyF` will have the `RowKey` value of another entity record in a different partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, casing is important. The properties were defined as `propertyA` in Table Storage, but `PropertyA` on the model, which meant they couldn't be resolved.

Updating the custom property names to capitalised case in Table Storage led to it correctly parsing the custom object when using `GetEntity<T>` and `Query<T>`.